# Recipe for disabling strict mode using Babel 7 and coffee-loader

Tags: webpack, coffeescript, babeljs

I can see the breaking change adding use strict everywhere since Babel v7.0

This is breaking my legacy code using `callee`. Looking for solutions to switch that off globally but all my attempts failed. Using babel-env and babel-preset-es2015.

Webpack rule to load coffee files is

```
{
  test: /\.coffee$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'coffee-loader',
      options: {
        transpile: {
          presets: ['es2015']
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But that always injects `use strict`. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
  test: /\.coffee$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'coffee-loader',
      options: {
        transpile: {
          presets: [['es2015', {modules: false}]]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```